# How can I get this font for 'G'?

Tags: fonts

How can I type [image: Font for 'G'] in LaTeX? I want to type (\Omega)[image: G]is
a measure space.

Comment: This tool can help you identify the markup for symbols: https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: @JasperHabicht,Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `\mathscr{G}` with [`mathrsfs`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathrsfs).